# Nav submenu covers links/content below it even when hidden

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

Ok so I recently had to redo my side navigation to make it more mobile friendly as the other one wasn't working correctly.

Therefore I found one I thought I would try, but I admit I am not as familiar with, and while I was able to tweak almost everything I still have one large issue.

I have a side navigation submenu that pops out with other options, then is hidden.
However even when hidden, it is still technically there covering up vital links that can no longer be clicked.. upon testing in IE (I had only previously looked in Safari and Firefox and didn't notice it because the menu was hidden) I can now see a scrollbar clearly showing what is happening, the menu still exists over the content below, it is simply hidden.

How can I make this menu only pop out and cover content upon scrolling over it's parent, but to be actually hidden (or moved off screen) when not in use so that links below it can still be clicked. You can see the problem navigation here (scroll over the "products" link): http://www.pioneerpartygroup.com/license_product/disney.php

As you can see if you try to click "cars", "Cinderella", "Nemo" and the left side links they are all unclickable because the menu is technically still covering them, just invisible.

Here is the menu code:

```
<ul class="parent-menu">
<br />

<hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">

<li><a href="#">Products&nbsp;&nbsp;&raquo;</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="/accessories.php">Balloon Accessories</a></li>
<li><a href="/funsational.php">Funsational Products</a></li>
<li><a href="/just_write.php">Just Write Products</a></li>
<li><a href="/license_product/license_product.php">Licensed Characters</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.masterbow.com" target="_blank">MasterBow Products</a></li>
<li><a href="/partymate.php">PartyMate Products</a></li>
<li><a href="/qualatex.php">Qualatex Products</a></li>
<li><a href="/water.php">Water Products</a></li>
</ul>
</li>


<hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
<li><a href="dinodan.php" >Dino Dan</a>

</li>

<hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
<li><a href="disney.php">Disney</a></li>

<hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
<li><a href="dreamworks.php" >Dreamworks</a>

</li>

<hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
<li><a href="el_chavo.php" >El Chavo</a>

</li>

<hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
<li><a href="hellokitty.php" >Hello Kitty</a>

</li>

<hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
<li><a href="hit_entertainment.php" >HiT Entertainment</a>

</li>

<hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">

<li><a href="marvel.php">Marvel</a></li>

 <hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
 <li><a href="nascar.php" >Nascar</a>

 </li>

 <hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
 <li><a href="nickelodeon.php" >Nickelodeon</a>

 </li>

 <hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
 <li><a href="pacman.php" >Pacman</a>

 </li>

 <hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
 <li><a href="pocoyo.php" >Pocoyo</a>

 </li>

 <hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
 <li><a href="precious_moments.php" >Precious Moments</a>

 </li>

 <hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
 <li><a href="trashpack.php" >The Trash Pack</a>

 </li>

 <hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
 <li><a href="smurfs.php" >The Smurfs </a>

 </li>

 <hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">
 <li><a href="warnerbrothers.php">Warner Brothers</a>

 </li>

 <hr class="hr" width="164" size="2" align="left" color="#FFFFFF">     

 </ul>

 </nav>
```

And here is the .css

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
ul, li, nav {

    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


#menu {
    overflow: auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.parent-menu {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    min-width:165px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#menu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#menu ul li a {
    padding:10px 15px;
    display:block;
    color:#656565;
    text-decoration:none;
}


#menu ul li a:hover {
    left:165px;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#a8a8a8;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}

#menu ul li:hover  ul {
    left: 165px;
    width:165px;
    height:280px;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#000;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


#menu ul li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    color:#FFF;

    background-color: #000;

    top: 0;

    left: -165px;

    min-width: 165px;

    z-index: -1;

    height: 100%;

    -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

    -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

    -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

    transition: left 200ms ease-in;
}


#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#0c8fff;
}
```

I know that it has to be something to do with the left:165px and left:-165px because essentially when not hovered over, the submenu should be placed -165px (underneath the main menu and therefore not seen) and then upon hover, moved 165px to the right to where it becomes visible for the viewer, then in theory upon not hovering again, it moves back once more to -165 but this doesn't seen to be happening.

Any help is appreciated, I think I am just missing something simple, maybe another left:-165px that needs to be added somewhere to keep it hidden until hovered?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did, however, solve my issue.

I had the overflow set to :auto so it was just hidden essentially.
I changed it to visible, then adjusted so the submenu actually hides for real behind the main menu.

```
#menu {
        overflow: visible;
        position:relative;
        z-index:2;
            margin: 0;
padding: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause is pretty simple. Your menu is wrapped in a really deep nested table that is overlapping some of your links with a width of 350px for the submenu.

I would recommend to rethink the structure of your site: You have a simple layout that doesnt need any table structure. Just remove the table structure and use a simple grid system like (bootstrap or zurb might help) with 1 column for your navigation and 11 columns for the rest of the side. This would solve your navigation problem and would make your site responsiv for mobile devices.

Comment: Unfortunately I am working with a design someone else made, so while my newer designs eliminate tables and use divs and fluid code this particular site would need an entire overhaul to solve that.

Comment: I did, however, solve my issue.

I had the overflow set to :auto so it was just hidden essentially.
I changed it to visible, then adjusted so the submenu actually hides for real behind the main menu.

   #menu {
            overflow: visible;
            position:relative;
            z-index:2;
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
        }